# Is it possible to verify the developer payload on a server?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'm building a backend to an Android app with In-App Billing. Google recommends setting a unique [developer payload](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html#payload) for verifying purchases.

I'm planning to generate this payload on device at the time of purchase and store it on my backend server for validation later or if the user logs in on another device.

For additional verification, I'd like to have the server verify the token at the time it receives it to (a) ensures it is valid and (b) is tied to the user I think it is. Does Google provide an API for this, or can we only verify in the Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM moment :) The [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) can handle this.

- For product purchases, use [Purchases.products: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get)
- For subscription purchases, use [Purchases.subscriptions: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get)